# Asserting properties are present producing unexpected results

Tags: javascript, node.js

So this is my code

```
let user = {
    fName: 'Kado',
    lName: 'Kliewer',
    uName: 'kKliewer23',
    age: 18,
};

function helloUser(user) {
    if(user.fName === true && user.lName === true && user.age >= 18) {
        console.log(`Hello ${user.uName}. Welcome to the world of wonders.`);
    } else {
        console.log("Please get a parent's permission before playing this game.")
    }
};

helloUser(user);
```

I'm brand new to coding and JavaScript but I'm a little confused on the relationship between objects and functions. When I run my code it logs "Please get a parent's permission before playing this game.

I have tried making the first part of my if/else statement to equal true but it evaluated to the same answer. Could someone please explain this and help me?

Comment: `user.fName === true` - This condition is `false`.  (As is `user.lName === true`, for the same reason.)  What condition are you *trying* to test for there?

Comment: You probably mean `if (user.fName && ...)` as `"Kado"` is not `true`.

Comment: I am trying to practice writing and understanding how JavaScript works.  I was under the impression that every string value will equate to false, however when I entered that I didn't get the result I planned. The reason I want it to equal true or false is because someone else could enter a different uName or fName or even lName so I'm looking to make sure that is is a string not a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use
`user.fName === true && user.lName === true && user.age >= 18`

It means : `user.fName` equals to `true` and `user.lName`  equals to `true`

Since `user.fName` = "Kado", etc, this condition is unsuccessful hence it goes into the `else`

Comment: Mark it as answer, if helped you solve the problem :) @kado-kliewer23

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in if statement condition:

```
if(user.fName === true && user.lName === true && user.age >= 18)
```

It says if user.fName is equal to boolean `true` and user.lname is equal to boolean `true` and user.age is at least 18. And if all of these conditions are true `` console.log(`Hello ${user.uName}. Welcome to the world of wonders.`); `` will work otherwise else statement.

If you want to check if user has `fname`, `lname`, and `age >=18` then this condition would work:

```
function helloUser(user) {
    if(user.fName && user.lName && user.age >= 18) {
        console.log(`Hello ${user.uName}. Welcome to the world of wonders.`);
    } else {
        console.log("Please get a parent's permission before playing this game.")
    }
};
```